# Update is not a member of tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to add data into my Access database in Visual Basic, but I encount this error when I try to run my code:

> Error 1   'Update' is not a member of
>   'GestiuneStudenti.Gestiune_StudentiDataSetTableAdapters.Gestiune_StudentiTableAdapter'.   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\GestiuneStudenti\GestiuneStudenti\Form1.vb  64  13  GestiuneStudenti

Here is a sample of my code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            Gestiune_StudentiBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Gestiune_StudentiTableAdapter.Update(Gestiune_StudentiDataSet.Gestiune_Studenti)
            MessageBox.Show("Intrarea a fost adaugata cu succes")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Eroare la adaugarea intrarii")
        End Try
```

My database has 3 tables, 2 with primary key, and the third one with the primary keys from the other 2 tables as foreign key.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

- Explore open the XXXXDataSet.XSD
- Right click the TableAdapter
- Choose from the menu Configure and click the Advanced Options button
- Click the Generate Insert, Update and Delete Statement Box and the Okay Button
- Click the Finish Button

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a dataset you only need thses

```
Gestiune_StudentiTableAdapter.Update(Gestiune_StudentiDataSet)
```

I hope it help